# How to collect data from two related tables

Tags: json

I am trying to get data from two different tables: `users` and `comments`.
I want to return comment data and user data depending on the `commentsenderid` .

```php
<?php
$commentpostid = $_POST['commentpostid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments where commentpostid = '{$commentpostid}'";
$sqll = mysqli_query($db, $sql); // $db->query() is also accepted.
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($sqll, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Result:

```json
[
  {
    "commentid": "93",
    "comment": "naber kankam Benin",
    "commentpostid": "1006",
    "commentsenderid": "12"
  },
  {
    "commentid": "95",
    "comment": "kankam selam!",
    "commentpostid": "1006",
    "commentsenderid": "3135"
  }
]
```

Should be:

```json
[
  {
    "commentid": "93",
    "comment": "naber kankam Benin",
    "commentpostid": "1006",
    "commentsenderid": "12",
    "username": "denemeuser",
    "userbolum": "denemebolum",
    "useryas": "useryasdeneme"
  },
  {
    "commentid": "95",
    "comment": "kankam selam!",
    "commentpostid": "1006",
    "commentsenderid": "3135",
    "username": "denemeuser",
    "userbolum": "denemebolum",
    "useryas": "useryasdeneme"
  }
]
```

[[image: phpMyAdmin structure]]
[[image: JSON structure]]

Comment: You should go look into JOINs.

Comment: of i understood right, the tables are connected via FK, so why not just use a simple join?

Comment: i tried to do it using joins but i couldn't, it didnt return it as a json

Comment: JOIN will connect you with the data in the database, and return you a complete set of data. Whether you will convert this data to JSON is a completely separate matter.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 1):

You select all comments, join them with users whose id matches the id of the authors of comments, you select only those whose post matches the value you are looking for.

```sql
SELECT c.*, u.username, u.userbolum, u.useryas
FROM comments c
         JOIN users u ON c.commentsenderid = u.userid
WHERE commentpostid = ?
```

Comment: THANKS THIS WORKED;
SELECT*FROM comments INNER JOIN users ON comments.commentsenderid = users.userid WHERE commentpostid = '".$commentpostid."'

Comment: btw: `JOIN` = `INNER JOIN` @NewbieDeveloper  If this solution helped you, please click that this is the solution to your question.